# Can't install library tkinterhtml on Anaconda Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, jupyter

I'm having some trouble trying to install tkinterhtml. When I installed another library called "folium" it gave me no problems. But now all I'm able to get is:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - tkinterhtml

Current channels:

  - conda.anaconda.org/dsm/win-64
  - conda.anaconda.org/dsm/noarch
  - repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
  - conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
  - conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to
anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

I've tried installing multiple chanels such as conda-forge (although I don't know very well what I'm doing). I also searched in the anaconda official webpage and it seems to have that library available. Despite this when using command

```
conda install -c dsm tkinterhtml
```

it doesn't work either.

If anyone knows what could I do, I would very much greateful.

Comment: The information you are betting back from conda is telling you a lot. You are leaving out some information in your post though. What type of system are you trying this on? As you can see [here](https://anaconda.org/dsm/tkinterhtml) that command `%conda install -c dsm tkinterhtml` is only going to work in theory on linux. And if you are on linux, you probably have things in that environment incompatible with that **very old** package. That is basically what the information you are getting is saying, I suspect. You may be able to try and set up a new, separate environment ...

Comment: <continued> focusing on trying to install that very old software package. However, it may not be entirely possible if something your Anaconda/conda has installed is just not old enough. I'm thinking of more 'infrastructure' type software it may be using. More than likely you don't want this software given it has not been updated in about 7 years. If you insist...Based on [here](https://pypi.org/project/tkinterhtml/), you could try running in a cell in your notebook `%pip install tkinterhtml` and then restart the kernel to try the import statement. Still based on ...

Comment: <continued> [here](https://bitbucket.org/aivarannamaa/tkinterhtml/src/master/) this is unlikely as it hasn't been maintained to work with current Python. And more importantly, as tkinter is a separate GUI system itself, it probably also isn't compatible with Jupyter which is a GUI system onto itself. tkinter predates Jupyter. Jupyter is a more modern, browser-based approach to fulfilling the same role as tkinter for sharing Python based software. You probably should say what you are trying to accomplish and use modern Jupyter-based approaches to address that.

Comment: Using pip install seemed to work. Thank you very much. I am trying all of this in windows so that's maybe why it didn't work. It was strange for me because i made a small calculator interface with tkinter and it didn't seem to interfere with jupyer itself.  I had the same problem with trying to install the pygame package and pip install did the trick so thanks again. I'm still learning, hoping to improve :).